# laravel 5.5 Midtrans Api curl

Tags: php, laravel, curl

i'm working  for project that's use Midtrans payment, so i use Api curl from [ixudra/curl](https://github.com/ixudra/curl), from that i try to implemen to my controller i got this code

```
 public function index()
{
    $response = Curl::to('https://api.sandbox.midtrans.com/v2/token')
     ->withHeader('Content-Type: application/json')
    ->withHeader('Accept: application/json')
    ->withHeader('Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxx')

    ->withData( array( 'card_number' => '4811111111111114' ) )
    ->withData( array( 'card_cvv' => '123' ) )
    ->withData( array( 'card_exp_month' => '01' ) )
    ->withData( array( 'card_exp_year' => '2020' ) )
    ->withData( array( 'client_key' => 'SB-Mid-client-xxxxxxxxxx' ) )

    ->asJson()
    ->returnResponseObject()
    ->get();

    return response()->json($response);
}
```

then i got this return json

```
content 
status_code "400"
status_message  "One or more parameters in the payload is invalid."
id  "49ab5da0-6df2-4843-a1ed-cfedfea61798"
validation_messages 
0   "unsupported token request parameter(s)"
status  200
contentType "application/json"
```

i think there's somwthing wrong with my code because, i try implement to postman, and it's working and return token

Comment: try changing your content-type header into application/json

Comment: it's return same return

Answer (score 1):

First look [header](https://api-docs.midtrans.com/#http-s-header).

```
->withHeader('Content-Type: application/json')
->withHeader('Accept: application/json')
```

method `get`.

Comment: okay that's first thanks, after i run again return diverent the respose json, please check, i have been edit my question

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, i change all ->withData() whith this

```
->withData( array( 'card_number' => '4811111111111114','card_cvv' => '123','card_exp_month' => '01','card_exp_year' => '2020','client_key' => 'xxxxxxx' ) )
```

Comment: try not post your client key next time when asking question. that's dangers